# When I rename a column, how do I ensure my views aren't referencing the column by the old name in my test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I encountered a situation where I've renamed a column, but was unaware that my views were still referencing the column by the old name.

This broke my web app, and I pushed these changes to my production server, thus learning the importance of a test suite.

I'm new to testing, so, I'm wondering: how I can catch problems caused by this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found [this article](https://www.sit.auckland.ac.nz/Unit_and_Functional_Testing_for_Rails). It explains functional tests, which is what I need to test my views/actions.

The documentation on rails functional testing seems poor, but the article I linked to above is exactly what I was looking for.

I just didn't understand where/how views are supposed to be tested, alas, in the functional tests.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Use the view in one of your tests. After the rename, the test will fail.

Comment: Is there a simple way to just test to make sure my controllers don't raise exceptions?

Comment: Running a suite of tests sure seems simple.  What simpler thing are you looking for?